# Xamarin | Images "flash" when resume the page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my demo app I have a listview with some items (obtained by json api) and, simply, when I click on an item, I open another page. When I go back to the first page, the images flash.
This is the first page code:

```
namespace AppProva
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {

        private const string Url = "http://myurl.it/api/get_events.php";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        private ObservableCollection<Event> _events;
        public Page1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mEvent = e.Item as Event;
            //DisplayAlert("Tap", mEvent.name, "OK");
            itemListView.SelectedItem = null;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new OpenOtherPage(mEvent));
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Event>>(content);

            _events = new ObservableCollection<Event>(events);
            itemListView.ItemsSource = _events;

            base.OnAppearing();
        }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <ListView x:Name="itemListView" HasUnevenRows="True"
                  ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="{Binding image}" HeightRequest="200 "/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                    <!--<ImageCell Text="{Binding name}" Detail="{Binding descr}" ImageSource="{Binding image}"/>-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I've tested it on an Android emulator and on my Android phone, same problem.

Comment: You are resetting the binding source during the Page's `OnAppearing` event, so it is reloading the content (and thus the images)

Comment: Oh, yes. I will try soon, but probably you've solved my problem. I'm a noob with C# and Xamarin.